# How to replace “right click” by using modifier key + left click in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, right-click

I'm using Windows 10 and use the iPad as my graphic tablet. I connect them via WiFi using the 'duet display' app. The problem is that the apple pencil only has 1 button. So to do right-click in Windows 10, I can only do that using mouse or touchpad or shift FIO.

In Mac , there is solution where i can do right-click by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>. So in iPad i can still using Apple Pencil. But in windows 10, how can I do right-click by using <kbd>LMB</kbd>?